# Reclycerview swipe lock and revert

Tags: java, android, swipe

is it possible to lock swipe and revert in reclyerview.please guide[image: LIKE THIS]

Comment: define your problem

Comment: Unless you want to implement your own solution there are several libraries availablie that does this for you, for example https://github.com/TUBB/SwipeMenu.